# Tag Key.How to add an tag while pressing enter button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the tag.js for adding key tag.The tag gets added only on pressing comma button.Similarly The tag can be deleted using backspace.

I want to use enter button to add tags?
How to do it?
I tried using keycode 13 that I have hide the code in below js.

```js
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('tags-input'), function (el) {
    let hiddenInput = document.createElement('input'),
        mainInput = document.createElement('input'),
        tags = [];
    
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', el.getAttribute('data-name'));

    mainInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    mainInput.classList.add('main-input');
    mainInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
        let enteredTags = mainInput.value.split(',');
        if (enteredTags.length > 1) {
            enteredTags.forEach(function (t) {
                let filteredTag = filterTag(t);
                if (filteredTag.length > 0)
                    addTag(filteredTag);
            });
            mainInput.value = '';
        }
    });

    mainInput.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        let keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
        if (keyCode === 8 && mainInput.value.length === 0 && tags.length > 0) {
            removeTag(tags.length - 1);
        }

        // if (keyCode === 13 && mainInput.value.length === 1 && tags.length > 0) {
           
        // }


    });

    el.appendChild(mainInput);
    el.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    addTag('hello!');
     

    function addTag (text) {
        let tag = {
            text: text,
            element: document.createElement('span'),
        };

        tag.element.classList.add('tag');
        tag.element.textContent = tag.text;

        let closeBtn = document.createElement('span');
        closeBtn.classList.add('close');
        closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            removeTag(tags.indexOf(tag));
        });
        tag.element.appendChild(closeBtn);

        tags.push(tag);

        el.insertBefore(tag.element, mainInput);

        refreshTags();
    }

    function removeTag (index) {
        let tag = tags[index];
        tags.splice(index, 1);
        el.removeChild(tag.element);
        refreshTags();
    }

    function refreshTags () {
        let tagsList = [];
        tags.forEach(function (t) {
            tagsList.push(t.text);
        });
        hiddenInput.value = tagsList.join(',');
    }

    function filterTag (tag) {
        return tag.replace(/[^\w -]/g, '').trim().replace(/\W+/g, '-');
    }
});
```

```css
:root {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.tags-input {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    display: inline-block;
}

.tags-input .tag {
    font-size: 85%;
    padding: 0.5em 0.75em;
    margin: 0.25em 0.1em;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ddd;
    transition: all 0.1s linear;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tags-input .tag:hover {
    background-color: #3af;
    color: white;
}

.tags-input .tag .close::after {
    content: '×';
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: scale(1.4);
    margin-left: 0.75em;
}

.tags-input .tag .close:hover::after {
    color: red;
}

.tags-input .main-input {
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0.5em 0.1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Input Tags</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="tags.css">
          <script src="tags.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            Enter some tags:
        </p>
        <p>
            <div class="tags-input" data-name="tags-input">
               <!--  <span class="tag">CSS<span class="close"></span></span>
                <span class="tag">JavaScript<span class="close"></span></span>
                <span class="tag">HTML<span class="close"></span></span> -->
            </div>
        </p>
          <script src="tags.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How to add another tag while pressing enter button?
I want the code similar to the tags functionality used in stack overflow.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this will help. Thank you.

```js
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('tags-input'), function (el) {
    let hiddenInput = document.createElement('input'),
        mainInput = document.createElement('input'),
        tags = [];
    
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', el.getAttribute('data-name'));

    mainInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    mainInput.classList.add('main-input');
    mainInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
        let enteredTags = mainInput.value.split(',');
        if (enteredTags.length > 1) {
            enteredTags.forEach(function (t) {
                let filteredTag = filterTag(t);
                if (filteredTag.length > 0)
                    addTag(filteredTag);
            });
            mainInput.value = '';
        }
    });

    mainInput.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        let keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
        if (keyCode === 8 && mainInput.value.length === 0 && tags.length > 0) {
            removeTag(tags.length - 1);
        }

       if (keyCode === 13 && mainInput.value.length > 0 && tags.length > 0) {
             addTag(mainInput.value);
             mainInput.value ="";
        }


    });

    el.appendChild(mainInput);
    el.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    addTag('hello!');
     

    function addTag (text) {
        let tag = {
            text: text,
            element: document.createElement('span'),
        };

        tag.element.classList.add('tag');
        tag.element.textContent = tag.text;

        let closeBtn = document.createElement('span');
        closeBtn.classList.add('close');
        closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            removeTag(tags.indexOf(tag));
        });
        tag.element.appendChild(closeBtn);

        tags.push(tag);

        el.insertBefore(tag.element, mainInput);

        refreshTags();
    }

    function removeTag (index) {
        let tag = tags[index];
        tags.splice(index, 1);
        el.removeChild(tag.element);
        refreshTags();
    }

    function refreshTags () {
        let tagsList = [];
        tags.forEach(function (t) {
            tagsList.push(t.text);
        });
        hiddenInput.value = tagsList.join(',');
    }

    function filterTag (tag) {
        return tag.replace(/[^\w -]/g, '').trim().replace(/\W+/g, '-');
    }
});
```

```css
:root {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.tags-input {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    display: inline-block;
}

.tags-input .tag {
    font-size: 85%;
    padding: 0.5em 0.75em;
    margin: 0.25em 0.1em;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ddd;
    transition: all 0.1s linear;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tags-input .tag:hover {
    background-color: #3af;
    color: white;
}

.tags-input .tag .close::after {
    content: '×';
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: scale(1.4);
    margin-left: 0.75em;
}

.tags-input .tag .close:hover::after {
    color: red;
}

.tags-input .main-input {
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0.5em 0.1em;
}
```

```html
<p>Enter some tags:</p>
<div class="tags-input" data-name="tags-input"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Alexis.This is what I expected.It was useful.

Comment: You can also check the duplication of tag names in the same if condition itself. Thank you.

Comment: Okiee.One more doubt.How to store certain values and get the value while keying up.For example If I type the letter j,then it should start showing the simliar words such as java,javascript,etc...?Is is possible to do that?